# What happens if I am unable to upload my binary to the app store in 180 days..?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I received a mail from Apple that I only have 7 days left to upload the binary or the app name will be forfeited. Can I extend this once it forfeited if somebody does not use it..?

Comment: Get something into review ASAP. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html or THEY WILL delete it and you will not get the name back easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one solution would be for you to delete the app from itunesconnect and then use "add new application" to add another one with same name.

Comment: is it allowed..? I don't have much knowledge about the app store.. I have only worked on Enterprise applications.. :/

Comment: I think this is not possible. You can not reuse the name of an app even after you delete it. Once assigned is assigned. Could anyone confirm this please?

Comment: You can reuse the name - you can't reuse AppId. This method is viable if the app was not already on the App Store. If it was: you'll loose all the ratings and comments.

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you will not upload app in 180 days, then apple will remove your app data from account. And other company/person can use your app name.

And if you don't want that, then just remove the app by "Delete App" button then re-submit the app by entering all data.

Cheers!